# How to save a JSON-object and use it in another request?

Tags: json, jmeter

i'm currently trying to set up some JMeter testplans. I am pretty new to this (started a week ago) and don't have much programming experience either, so i hope you could help me in this case.

I already set up some http requests and have some simple JSON Extractor post processors to save some of the variables and use them with the "${variable}" notation.

But now i need to save and modify an object from a response to use that in the next http request.

My respose is a extremely big JSON object and the part im interested in looks something like this:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "workspace": {
      "resultInstance": [
       [{"part": "1"...}],
       [{"part": "2"...}],
       ...
       [{"part": "20"...}]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that for whatever reason these objects {"part":"1"...} are inside a nested array. And they are also pretty big.

I would like to safe those objects in a variable to use them in my next http request which **should** looks like this:

```
{
  "instanceChange": {
    "functionChecks": [
      {"part": "1"...},
      {"part": "2"...},
      ...
      {"part": "20"...}
    ]
  }
}
```

So what im really trying to find is a way to save all of the possible objects inside the nested array "resultInstance" and put them inside the non nested array "functionChecks".

I already looked inside the JMeter documentation but because of my poor programming background i cant find a way to realize this.

I think i need something like the JSR223 PostProcessor and "simply go through the resultInstance-array and use smth. like an getObject() on these", but i cant figure out the code i need and if its even possible to safe objects in variables in Jmeter.

Im pretty thankful for every bit of help or advice :).

Thanks in advance,

aiksn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the JSON response
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
   def request = ['instanceChange': ['functionChecks': response.payload.workspace.resultInstance]]
   vars.put('request', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(request).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. That's it, you should be able to refer the generated request body as `${request}` where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri!
With your code and the documentation about Groovy i could produce the colde i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let response ={
  "payload": {
    "workspace": {
      "resultInstance": [
       [{"part": "1"...}],
       [{"part": "2"...}],
       ...
       [{"part": "20"...}]
      ]
    }
  }
};

let requestObj={
  "instanceChange": {
    "functionChecks": [
    ]
  }
};

response.payload.workspace.resultInstance.forEach(myFunction);

 myFunction(item, index) {
requestObj.instance.functionsCheck.push(item[0]);
 }
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer because it uses JavaScript (the JSR223 PostProcessor must be set to use a JavaScript engine)